# Help calculating angles for woodworking

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, angle

I am working on a wood working project and need to cut some 2 x 2's on an angle in order to form an X inscribed inside a rectangle. Visually here is what I am trying to create:

[image]

So basically I want to figure out what the angle $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are so that I can cut the wood to form the X inside the rectangle. The rectangle is 30 inches by 16.5 inches and the width of the wood for the X is 2 inches. I tried using simple trigonometry/geometry to figure it out but have been stumped so far as to how to do it. Also, what would the length of each piece of wood making up the X?

Comment: What is the width of the wood on the border of the rectangle ?

Comment: @stity Although not to scale, the widths of all the woods are 2 inches.

Comment: @Vikram thanks, but I don't want to have to specify the value of $\beta$ to get $\alpha$

Comment: Small caution. The actual width of a nominal $2 \times 2$ is a little less than $2$ inches. Measure, and recompute if necessary.

Comment: @EthanBolker very true! The 2x2's I have are the standard 1.5x1.5 but I figured I would use 2 inches for the problem and then recalculate it on my own later using the actual 1.5 inches.

Answer (score 1):

Given a rectangle origin centered with external dimensions height $h$ and width $w$ and build with $\delta$ thick woods, to construct the needed two diagonals we proceed as follows. First we consider a circle origin centered with radius $\delta/2$. After that a line tangent to this circle and passing through the inner rectangle corner, will give us the desired angle $\alpha$. Calling $\alpha_0 = \arctan\left(\frac{h/2-\delta}{w/2-\delta}\right)$ and $\gamma = \arctan\left(\frac{\delta/2}{\sqrt{(h/2-\delta)^2+(w/2-\delta^2)-(\delta/2)^2}}\right)$ we have $\alpha = \alpha_0-\gamma$ or

$$
\alpha = \arctan\left(\frac{h/2-\delta}{w/2-\delta}\right)-\arctan\left(\frac{\delta/2}{\sqrt{(h/2-\delta)^2+(w/2-\delta^2)-(\delta/2)^2}}\right)
$$

now using the trigonometric formula $\tan(a-b) = \frac{\tan a-\tan b}{1+\tan a\tan b}$ we obtain easily

$$
\tan\alpha = \frac{4 \delta^2+h w-\delta \left(\sqrt{7 \delta^2-4 \delta (h+w)+h^2+w^2}+2 h+2 w\right)}{3 \delta^2-4 \delta w+w^2}
$$

and for $h=30'',\ h = 16.5'', \ \delta = 2''$ we obtain

$$
\alpha = 1.75659\ \text{rad} = 60.3478^{\circ}
$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you let $s$ be the length of wood in the bottom left of the $X$ that touches the side, then you get $$\tan(\alpha) = \frac{s}{2}.$$

Additionally, we have that a right triangle with angle $\alpha$, adjacent side length $16.5 - 2 - 2 = 12.5$ and opposite side length $30 - 2 - 2 - s = 26 - s$.  This gives another equation of $$\tan(\alpha) = \frac{26 - s}{12.5}.$$  Putting the two equations together gives $$\tan(\alpha) = \frac{52}{29}.$$  This gives $\alpha = \arctan(52/29) \approx 60.85^\circ$.  Also, $\beta = 90^\circ - \alpha$.

I'm pretty sure this is right, but would appreciate if someone would double check this (especially since it's actually gonna be built!)

---

EDIT: The first equation is wrong, it should be $\cos(\alpha) = \frac{2}{s}$, implying $$\tan(\alpha) = \frac{26 - \frac{2}{\cos(\alpha)}}{12.5} \implies \alpha \approx 60.348^\circ$$.

Comment: The first equation is wrong : $cos(\alpha)=\frac{2}{s}$

Comment: This gives us $\alpha \approx 60.35°$

Comment: @stity, Yes!  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @MarcusM why does $\cos(\alpha)=2/s$? I'm having a hard time figuring out that part.

Comment: @RustyStatistician, perhaps an easier way to see it is to see that $\sin(\beta) = 2/s$ (which is equivalent); the angle inside of the wood is $\beta$, and if you draw the width as the opposite side of this angle you get a right triangle with hypotenuse $s$, opposite side $2$ and angle $\beta$.

Comment: @MarcusM thanks! As one last note, could you update you answer to show how you simplified those two equations into one and solved for it? Isn't $s$ unknown?

Comment: @RustyStatistician, oops that was a typo: it should read $2/\cos(\alpha)$.  You plug that in for $s$ and solve for $\alpha$ from Wolfram Alpha (or some other software).

Comment: @MarcusM are we able to solve for $\alpha$ in closed form or only using software as an approximation?

Comment: @RustyStatistician, You could solve for it explicitly, by replacing $\tan(\alpha)$ with $\sqrt{1 - \cos^2(\alpha)}/\cos(\alpha)$, multiplying both sides by $\cos(\alpha)$, squaring both sides and then explicitly solving the quadratic for $\cos(\alpha)$.  This gives an exact form for $\cos(\alpha)$, and you could then take $\arccos$ of both sides for an exact form.  I think the best you'll be able to do is $\arccos$ of something that has a square root it in.

Comment: The exact value would be $\alpha = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{-100+52\sqrt{3313}}{3329}\right)$