# "Barn Door" trig problem

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am mainly a computer science guy, currently trying to create a 3d model of a barn door.  This led me into an interesting little problem that my trigonometry skills are apparently too rusty to solve.

[image]

In the given illustration, $A$ and $B$ are known as well as $W$, The hypotenuse($C$) and its angle are obvious even to me, but this is not the same thing as the angle of the diagonal board.

What is the best way to calculate that?

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: If you have the length $B^\prime$ going just to the first edge of the diagonal board, then you can compute the angle as $\theta = \arctan \frac{A}{B^\prime}.$

Comment: Also, $B-B^\prime=\frac{W}{\sin \theta}.$

Comment: This has been asked before: [Help calculating angles for woodworking](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2379007/help-calculating-angles-for-woodworking)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use $\theta$ for the angle of the diagonal board, you can see that $$b=\frac{a}{\tan\theta}+\frac{w}{\sin\theta}$$ We can multiply this with $\sin\theta$, to get:
$$b\sin\theta=a\cos\theta+w$$
We would like to get $\theta$. The easy way is to square the above equation, use $\sin^2\theta=1-\cos^2\theta$, and you get a quadratic in $\cos\theta$. Use the positive solution. Can you take it from here?