# Parallel lines passing through rectangle angles

Tags: geometry, rectangles

I have a rectangle (side length L1 and L2) and two parallel lines passing through two opposite angles:

(sorry the image is missing due to stackexchange policy)

I know that the (perpendicular) distance between the parallel lines is h, and that each line form a right triangle with the sides of the rectangle (let's say L1 is the base of such triangle).

What is the formula to calculate the angles (alpha, beta) of this right triangle?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I understand the question is not particularly clear without an image. As a reference, you can look the flag of trinidad and tobago. Specifically the white stripes.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2379007/362967)?

Comment: Yes! Thank you!